# Finding a $z$ score with a standard deviation and an $x$ value

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My homework question says: "A distribution has a standard deviation of $5$. What is the $z$ score for a score that is above the mean by 10 points". Help! I don't know how to figure this out without knowing what the mean is prior to attempting the qusestion.

Answer (score 1):

The Z score is for a score $x$ is $$\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} $$ where $\mu$ is the mean and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation. If "$x$ is above the mean by ten points", that indicates that $x-\mu = 10.$

Answer (score 0):

The $z$ score is the number of standard deviations from the mean. You are already given the difference from the mean, so you can skip the usual step of subtracting from the mean.

If the standard deviation is $12$ and you're $12$ below the mean, then $z=-1$.  If you're $8$ above the mean, then that's $\frac23$ of a standard deviation above, so $z=\frac23$.  In the usual formulation $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$, you're already given $x-\mu$ so you don't need $x$ or $\mu$ individually to find $z$.

Comment: Ok so in this problem z would be 2? Because you would do 10/5?

Comment: @AbbyGrace That's correct! Since 5 points up would be 1 standard deviation, 10 points up would be 2 standard deviations.

Comment: @TobyMak thank you so much! It makes much more sense now!